# log can't write to logfile,but write to console

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I my project log4j.properties in classpath 
but when i use mvn assembly:assembly a *.tar.gz
and then tar xvf x.tar.gz

```
java -cp lib/*:. Test.main
```

the log output to console, not output to log4j.properites assignation log file.

```
➜   git:(master) ✗ ls -al lib/*log*
-rw-r--r--  1 fuyou  staff   60686  8 12 16:47 lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 fuyou  staff  367444  8  1 08:47 lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 fuyou  staff   20573 12  5 10:10 lib/logging-1.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 fuyou  staff   10792  8  1 08:47 lib/logstat-client-1.0.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 fuyou  staff   23786  8  1 08:47 lib/logstat-common-1.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 fuyou  staff    8869  9  4 15:28 lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
➜   git:(master) ✗ ls -al lib/*slf*
-rw-r--r--  1 fuyou  staff  26084  8 12 08:40 lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 fuyou  staff   8869  9  4 15:28 lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
➜   git:(master) ✗ ls -al lib/*jcl-over-slf4j*
zsh: no matches found: lib/*jcl-over-slf4j*
➜   git:(master) ✗ ls -al lib
```

add log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, root
log4j.appender.root=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.root.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.root.File=logs/test.log
log4j.appender.root.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.root.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c{2}  %m%n
log4j.appender.root.Append=true
```

Comment: The `log4j.properties` file in question?

Comment: i add log4.properties file content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you log4j.properties on the classpath at all? It needs to appear somewhere on the classpath (ideally in the root).

You can run `java -cp lib/*:. -Dlog4j.debug Test.main` to see which configuration file log4j is loading. If it isn't your log4j.properties, you might need to move yours to make log4j pick it up.

Another option is to just use `java -cp lib/*:. -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties Test.main` (note I've only ever used this with log4j.xml, so I can't guarantee it will work with log4j.properties).